# Neural network with both imaging and non-imaging data

Tags: deep-learning, convolution

I am attempting to construct a neural network architecture that uses an image of a location along with non-image information (local weather, census data) to accurately classify the location.

I know a CNN should be used to evaluate the image data, however I am unsure how to integrate the non-image data into the neural network. Should I use the output from the CNN as an input into a new feed-forward neural network with the non-imaged data as additional inputs? Or perhaps an ensemble approach with the CNN (imaging data) and feed-forward (non-imaging data).

Using Keras with TF backend, any helpful links/code/papers would be much appreciated!